# How to show local images in collection view with api called data labels names respectively

Tags: ios, swift, image, uicollectionview

Means !

I have one collection view which will have the image, label.
And i am doing one api call , to display the list of available name in my collection view label. For image i am giving the static images.

Now in my local image assets like start from names like `img1, img2,img3,img4` like that.

What i need is i need to show all the images one by one as per my label names.

Like this is my example :

**Label** :  `Apple,Orange,drums`  [ **I will have this order only no change]**

**Image** :

**Apple image `Named as img1`
orange image `Named as img2`
drums image `Named as img3`**

Now how can i so the respective images as per the label name.Here my code :

```
var AllNames = [String]()
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.getNames()
}


    func getNames(){
        Transport.sharedInstance.getname { (data, err) in
            if let _  = err{

            }else{
                if let dataa = data as? String{
                    if let dataFromString = dataa.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                        let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)

                       self.mobileOprator.removeAll()
                        for (_, val) in json {

                            self.AllNames.append(val.rawString()!)

                        }
                    }
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

So my `AllNames` will have all names. How can i achive my requirement.

Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand the question or the problem you're describing here. Could you be more specific or explain better the goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @cldrr  in my code `AllNames` contains the label name like `apple,orange,durms` from api call.The order will be like this and it will display in my collection view...Fine.....Now in my local mage assets i have list of images like `img1,img2,img3,` So this will have the respective images as per the order. For example `img1` have apple image as per label name . Now `img2` have `orange image`as per second label orange name label...I need to show thr respective image in my collection view ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the think you want to have, but anyway: you have a function called `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for creating the cells and configure them. This could look like that (plus `numberOfItemsInSection`):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allNames.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    let imageName = "img\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    myCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    myCell.label.text = allNames[indexPath.row]
    return myCell
}
```

The special line you are looking for is this here:

```
    let imageName = "img\(indexPath.row + 1)"
```

Not sure if that's what you are looking for?!